# Shortcut to the top in Terminal on macOS

Tags: macos, terminal

I want to check top line in the Terminal.app after working on it for all day long.

How to scroll back to top in a quick way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On a MacBook or an Apple keyboard, press <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> to scroll to the top and <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> to scroll to the bottom.

Comment: For context: On Macs, `fn`+ `←`/`↑`/`↓`/`→`  is used to trigger `home`/`page up`/`page down`/`end`, respectively, across the OS and not just in terminal